# Load NSDictionary into a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have this NSDictionary that I want to load into a table view.  It should have a cell for each dictionary to have a cell for it.  So 3 cells in this case.

```
friendsDictionary: (
        {
        name = Down;
        age = 15;
        birthday = Today;
    },
        {
        name = Charlie;
        age = 12;
        birthday = Today;
    },
        {
        name = Chris;
        age = 18;
        birthday = Today;
    }
```

Edit:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"friendsList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSDictionary *myDictionary = [dict objectForKey:@"friends"];
    self.friendsDictionary = myDictionary;
    [aDictionary release];
```

Comment: Happy Birthday Down, Charlie and Chris!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got there is actually an NSArray filled with 3 NSDictionaries.

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method you can reference your array (Assuming your array is a synthesized property) with `self.friendsDictionary`.

Therefore you can do `[[cell textLabel] setText:[[self.friendsDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];`

Check Apple's sample code for TableViews for more information on how to set up your `UITableViewController` subclass. Remember to implement numberOfRowsInSection: and return `[self.friendsDictionary count]`